# Laravel 4: A where and whereIn inside a whereHas using Eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Laravel 4 - advanced Where

I'm trying to retrieve `Posts` that have a `$keyword` like a certain `Companion` and besides that I want to retrieve the `Posts` the have a linking `title` or `content` as the `$keyword`. 
But when I try to use a `where` or `whereIn` inside a `whereHas` the query doesn't take these into account. When the state is 0 (not visible) or not inside the category 1 the Post item should not get selected.

```
$companion_id = Companion::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%' )->lists('id');
```

The code block below has to do two things:

1. Search for `Post` items with a `title` or `content` like the `$keyword`
2. **and** search for `Post` items that have `Companions` like the `$keyword`

code:

```
$results = Post::whereHas('companions', function($query) use($companion_id)
                {
                    $query->whereIn('companions.id', $companion_id)
                        ->where('state', '=', 1)
                        ->whereIn('category_id', array(1));
                })
                ->whereIn('category_id', array(1))
                ->orwhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%' )
                ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%' )
                ->where('state', '=', '1')
                ->orderBy('menu_order', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

The code above retrieves data succesfully except for the `where` and `whereIn` parts inside the `whereHas`.

Who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jarek Tkaczyk.
His answer was almost correct. All I had to do was wrap the `where` inside a `orWhere`. Now I get the `Posts` that has a `Companion` like the `$keyword` and I get the `Posts` that has the `$keyword` inside the `content` or `title`.

```
$results = Post::whereHas('companions', function($query) use($companion_id)
                {
                    $query->whereIn('companions.id', $companion_id)
                    ->where('state', '=', '1');
                })
                ->orWhere( function($q) use ( $keyword ) {
                    $q->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%' )
                      ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%' );
                })
                ->whereIn('category_id', array(1, 3))
                ->where('state', '=', '1')
                ->orderBy('menu_order', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. wrap your `orWhere` clauses in `(..)`
2. you don't need `where` and `whereIn` in the `whereHas` closure, since it queries `companions` table
3. you don't need `whereIn` for `category_id`, unless you want to pass multiple ids there

.

```
$results = Post::whereHas('companions', function($query) use($companion_id)
    {
        $query->whereIn('companions.id', $companion_id);
    })
    ->whereIn('category_id', array(1)) // why not where(..) ?
    ->where(function ($q) use ($keyword) {
      $q->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%' )
        ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%' );
    })
    ->where('state', '=', '1')
    ->orderBy('menu_order', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I try your code it returns nothing. What I basically want is to search for `Posts` that has say `Companion` X and search inside `Posts` `content` and `title` for the keyword X. My code does that except it does not look if the `Companion` and the `Posts` state is 1 and it doesn't look if the `Posts` are inside the required $category_id.

Comment: @Kordaat Yes, this code does exactly what you just said. It returns `posts` that have `title or content like %keyword%` and `category_id = 1` and `state = 1` and are related to `companion id in $companion_id`. Just make sure `$companion_id` is an array, otherwise just use `where` not `whereIn`. Your code returned different results, because it didn't care about most of your `where` clauses, due to *random* `or` placement.

Comment: All I had to change was the first `where` to `orWhere`. The `Posts` and `companions` both have a `state` so it is needed in both. I've posted the correct code below.

Comment: OK for both having `state`. But having `orWhere` there means that you look for either those `posts` with `companions` matching the closure **or** those with `content or title like %word%` - this is not what you asked for, so revise it and check whether that's what you needed in the end.

Comment: By using **or** I get both: `Posts` that has a `Companion` containing the keyword and I get the `Posts` containing the `keyword` in the `title` and/or `content`. When i use the `where` like you posted I'll only `Posts` when they have a `Companion` containing the keyword **and** the keyword in the title and/or content. In the last case there is none in my case. I'll adjust my question.